# "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" when trying to get item from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have such a code in order to fetch some data from a url:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.genderize.io/?name=joseph')
html = response.read()

>>> print html
{"name":"joseph","gender":"male","probability":"0.99","count":923}
```

Everything up to here is fine. But when I want to fetch "gender" data from this dictionary;

```
>>> print html["gender"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I get the above error.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: `html` is a string, try `json.loads(html)['gender']`.

Comment: Thank you Maroun. Please publish your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done, I tried to be more detailed. Let me know if you still have questions! Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `html` is of type string. To validate that, try:

```
>>> type(html)
<type 'str'>
```

Hence the error message saying that *string indices must be integers, not str*.

You should convert it to JSON using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
json.loads(html)['gender']
```